# .NET Equivalent of Replay Director

Tags: .net, debugging, production-environment

I would like to know if there's a 3rd-party tool for .NET that's equivalent to Replay Director.

Comment: @OP: for those of us who don't know what Replay Director is and who do not want to open a new tab to do a google search, just for answering your question, it would be nice if you can add what exactly is Replay Director

Comment: @Ram - thanks for the reminder. Anyway, to avoid risking a wrong description, here's the description from the company itself (http://www.replaysolutions.com):

"ReplayDIRECTOR™ is a patented software recording system that automates the process of reproducing, finding and fixing security, performance and application logic bugs" 

and this: 

"ReplayDIRECTOR captures the environment and execution of Java EE applications allowing for almost any issue to be reproduced and debugged at the source-code level without requiring access to the original environment, database, or application traffic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of something similar for .NET. The closest things I am aware of are [Isolator](http://site.typemock.com/) (manipulate function execution) and [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/) (has capability to reproduce concurrent states) - but that is a million miles away from what ReplayDirector does.